# How To Scrape Data From Button In Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I Want To Scrape Data From This Button How Can i Do Using Selenium Python

Here is the button screenshot:

[image]

Here is the website link: https://www.zameen.com/EstateAgents/Islamabad-3-152.html

Here is my code:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
for i  in range(1,154):
    driver.get('https://www.zameen.com/EstateAgents/Islamabad-3-' + str(i) + '.html')
    name = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('#agent_search_listing_section .title')
    number = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('.totalofnum:nth-child(3)')
    Total_Number =driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('.titanium-con+ .clearfix')
    button = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('#agent_phone').click()
    time.sleep(3)
    phone = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('.phone_click')
    items = len(name)
    with open(csv,'a') as s:
        for item in range(items):
            s.write(name[item].text + ',' + number[item].text + ',' + Total_Number[item].text + ',' + phone[item].text + '\n')
```

I Want to scrape Data From Call Button but i get this error when i try?

error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "scrap.py", line 16, in <module>
    button = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('#agent_phone').click()
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'click'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thing is you're using `find_elements_by_css_selector`, notice the `elements` in there, thats why it returns a list & your error says `'list' object has no attribute 'click'`. So either use

```
button = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#agent_phone').click()
```

or

```
button = driver.find_element_by_id('agent_phone').click()
```

Notice that we're using `element` here instead of `elements`